# Decode account data

Tags: typescript, account-data, deserialization, buffer-layout

I am trying to decode data from accounts.

This is the IDL for the data I want to decode:

```
{
      "name": "deployment",
      "type": {
        "kind": "struct",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "creator",
            "type": "publicKey"
          },
          {
            "name": "limitPerMint",
            "type": "u64"
          },
          {
            "name": "maxNumberOfTokens",
            "type": "u64"
          },
          {
            "name": "numberOfTokensIssued",
            "type": "u64"
          },
          {
            "name": "decimals",
            "type": "u8"
          },
          {
            "name": "useInscriptions",
            "type": "bool"
          },
          {
            "name": "deploymentType",
            "type": "u8"
          },
          {
            "name": "requireCreatorCosign",
            "type": "bool"
          },
          {
            "name": "migratedFromLegacy",
            "type": "bool"
          },
          {
            "name": "escrowNonFungibleCount",
            "type": "u64"
          },
          {
            "name": "ticker",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "deploymentTemplate",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "mintTemplate",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "fungibleMint",
            "type": "publicKey"
          },
          {
            "name": "offchainUrl",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
import { publicKey, u64, bool } from '@solana/buffer-layout-utils';
import { u32, u8, struct} from '@solana/buffer-layout';
import {Connection,PublicKey,} from "@solana/web3.js";

interface DeploymentAccount{
    discriminator: BN;
    creator: PublicKey;
    limitPerMint: BN;
    maxNumberOfTokens: BN;
    numberOfTokensIssued: BN;
    decimals: number;
    useInscriptions: boolean;
    deploymentType:number;
    requireCreatorCosign:boolean;
    migratedFromLegacy:boolean;
    escrowNonFungibleCount:BN;
    ticker: string;
    deploymentTemplate:string;
    mintTemplate:string;
    fungibleMint: PublicKey;
    offchainUrl:string;
}

const DeploymentAccountLayout = struct<DeploymentAccount>([
    u64("discriminator"),
    publicKey("creator"),
    u64("limitPerMint"),
    u64("maxNumberOfTokens"),
    u64("numberOfTokensIssued"),
    u8("decimals"),
    bool("useInscriptions"),
    u8("deploymentType"),
    bool("requireCreatorCosign"),
    bool("migratedFromLegacy"),
    u64("escrowNonFungibleCount"),
    u8("ticker"),
    u32("deploymentTemplate"),
    u32("mintTemplate"),
    publicKey("fungibleMint"),
    u64("offchainUrl"),
])

const connection = new Connection(rpc)
const accounts = await connection.getAccountInfo(new PublicKey('CDoPzZWsuZQ2GrJ4xWSkqomQLkXxK1FM7HUd2jSRTQKn'), "processed" )
const d = DeploymentAccountLayout.decode(accounts.data)
```

So far everything seems to work but I do not know what kind of bytes an string represent so I do no know what to assign for ticker, deployTemplate, mintTemplate, offchainUrl

This are the limits set on the contract:

```
pub const TICKER_LIMIT: usize = 200;
pub const TEMPLATE_LIMIT: usize = 1200;
pub const OFFCHAIN_URL_LIMIT: usize = 1200;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

Instead of using:

```
import { publicKey, u64, bool, u256, u128 } from '@solana/buffer-layout-utils';
import { u32, u8, struct} from '@solana/buffer-layout';
```

I used:

```
import * as borsh from "@coral-xyz/borsh"
```

And created the schema as follow:

```
const deploymentAccountSchema = borsh.struct<DeploymentAccount>([
    borsh.u64("discriminator"),
    borsh.publicKey("creator"),
    borsh.u64("limitPerMint"),
    borsh.u64("maxNumberOfTokens"),
    borsh.u64("numberOfTokensIssued"),
    borsh.u8("decimals"),
    borsh.bool("useInscriptions"),
    borsh.u8("deploymentType"),
    borsh.bool("requireCreatorCosign"),
    borsh.bool("migratedFromLegacy"),
    borsh.u64("escrowNonFungibleCount"),
    borsh.str("ticker"),
    borsh.str("deploymentTemplate"),
    borsh.str("mintTemplate"),
    borsh.publicKey("fungibleMint"),
    borsh.str("offchainUrl"),
])
```

This returns the data as expected

Answer (score 0):

If you have an IDL that Anchor generated like `export const IDL: MyProgram = { //...` and `export const IDL: MyProgram = { //...` you can automatically generate types like

```
export type SomeAccount = IdlAccounts<typeof IDL>["someAccount"];
```

Just make sure someAccount is actually the name in the IDL, and note that it is typically camelCase.

Comment: This is a nice one didn't know you can do that but my problem was creating the schema to decode the data

Comment: If you've done this you can do `const someAcc: someAccount = await program.account.someAccount.fetch(someKey);`